# Cannot reference an HTTPS SVG in PrestaShop

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg, prestashop

I'm currently trying to embed a JavaScript program in PrestaShop but I'm having a lot of difficulty using the application to load in external files.

The function loads in files when they're called by a normal HTTP URL, but not an HTTPS URL.

For example:

```
loadimage(https://somedomain.com/smile.svg);
```

isn't working in my PrestaShop site, but it is working on a simple HTML test site.

However:

```
loadimage(http://somedomain.com/smile.svg);
```

does work on the PrestaShop site.

If I navigate to the PHP file which handles the URL it's a similar result. I can browse:

```
localhost/imagehandle.php?image&image=http%3A%2F%somedomain.com%2Fsmile.svg
```

and the image loads properly and is displayed, however:

```
localhost/imagehandle.php?image&image=https%3A%2F%somedomain.com%2Fsmile.svg
```

will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution discovered, error is caused by the server's PHP not handling SSL properly, installed ibeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll and updated the php ini file to include external extensions and "extension=php_openssl.dll"